# PhpStorm LESS CSS Code Completion

Tags: css, autocomplete, less, code-completion, phpstorm

There is a [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) plug-in for [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)

`*.less` files are indeed recognized, in that a little "LESS" icon appears next to the `*.less` files, but it appears that the "support" ends there. **Code completion** does not work for me as it does for `*.css` files. I assume it's supposed to right? What could be the possible source of this problem?

I'm using PhpStorm on Windows 7.

**Edit:** After spending a good amount of time on this question, I've found no solution, and posted it as [a "bug" on YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-9393). Please also vote it up there, if you can't find an answer, and would like a fix to be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, in fact, a legitimate bug created due to a change in support for CSS code as explained in [this forum post](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/312030?tstart=0).

As one of the developers explains, autocompletion for LESS CSS code should be fixed in the near future.